# What is the difference between a CLR Worker Thread and a Worker Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, profiling

Looking at the Concurrency Analyzer, Threads view it appears my application produces far, far more threads than I would have thought.  Most of these are either a "CLR Worker Thread" or a "Worker Thread".

What are the differences?  Under what circumstances are each created?

[image: Clip of Concurrency Analyzer, Threads view]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Concurrency Visualizer is a pretty new but really cool! feature so there are a bit (I believe yet) of information regarding it, below what I've found in official information sources like MSDN:

- Worker thread - A thread that was created by the application main thread (*Main Thread* entry in the table)
- CLR Worker Thread - A worker thread that was created by the [Common Language Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bs2ecf4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Useful links:

- [Concurrency Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537632.aspx)
- [Channels (Threads View)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee329535.aspx)
- [Parallel Development in Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualizeparallel/) blog
- [Using the Concurrency Visualizer to Understand and Optimize UI Responsiveness](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualizeparallel/archive/2010/04/26/using-the-concurrency-visualizer-to-understand-and-optimize-ui-responsiveness.aspx)

Comment: Under what circumstances does the CLR create threads? Are these the threads created by [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx)?
Given your answer, I am also mystified by the sheer number of Worker Threads, I do not understand how I could have created so many.

Comment: Really hard to say without any look at your application code. CLR could create CLR worker threds for garbage collecting, regarding App threads, again this is only guesswork, but assuming that application uses Thread Pool there is well documented behaviour - "if the application queues up tasks for the thread pool faster than the one thread can handle it, then the thread pool will create additional threads.", and "The cool thing about a thread pool is that it is heuristic. If your application needs to perform many tasks, then the thread pool creates more threads."

Comment: Looking at the screenshot you have only one active application thread  (except Main thread) which is purple on timeline graph, thi mean it involved in I/O operation (you are reading file/network stream, io port or like that), all other threads are blocked for sync. I have no idea why you have many blocked worker threads, are you creating threads in some synchronized loop?